# How can I use a float for the bin size in a histogram plot?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, histogram

I have a list and I want to make a histogram plot in Python using a bin size of 0.01:

```
plt.hist(list, bins = 0.01)
```

I keep getting a type error saying bins can only be an integer, string or an array. Is there anyway to plot a histogram in Python using a float for the binsize?

Comment: Ìs your question answered now or is it still open?

Answer (score 4):

First off, try not to name your variables with words with a special meaning. A variable with name `list` prevents using the `list` command further in the code.

The [`bins=`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist.html) parameter can be a single number, in which case it is interpreted as the number of bins. So, it needs to be a strictly positive integer.  If you want to set a specific bin size, you need to give a complete list of the desired bin edges. The easiest way uses `np.arange(start, stop, step)`.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

mylist = np.random.randn(1000) / 10
plt.hist(mylist, bins=np.arange(min(mylist), max(mylist)+0.01, step=0.01), color='turquoise')
```

[image: example plot]

If the minimum isn't a nice round number, `np.arange` will follow that pattern. To get "nice" values for the bin edges, you could round the `start` of `np.arange`.  E.g.:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

mylist = np.random.randn(10, 1000).cumsum(axis=1).ravel() / 500
step = 0.01
start = np.floor(min(mylist) / step) * step
stop = max(mylist) + step
bin_edges = np.arange(start, stop, step=step)
plt.hist(mylist, bins=bin_edges, color='crimson', ec='white')
plt.xticks(bin_edges, rotation=90)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: rounded bin edges]

PS: Note that seaborn's [`sns.histplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.histplot.html) supports many more parameters than just matplotlib's `plt.hist`. `sns.histplot` has the possibility to choose a `binwidth` and/or a `binrange`, but also different types of statistics.